# Script has started showing broken image icon

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-drive-api

I have a script which selects an image from a directory based on the date.  It has worked for a few years, finding the correct image and showing it.  However, now it shows the broken image icon.  The logic still works and finds the correct src reference (if I cut and paste the URL from debug, a page shows with the image).  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong such that the image no longer shows from the script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
          
<style>
  .titleFormat
    {
      font-family:    Lato;
      font-size:      17px;
      font-weight:    bold;
      color:          rgba(34,110,147,1)
    }
  .bodyFormat
    {
      font-family:    Lato;
      font-size:      15px;
      font-weight:    normal;
      color:          black;
    }
    .imgFormat {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }

</style>

    <h2 id="title" class="titleFormat">Wreck of the day:</h2>

    <p id="wreckText" class="bodyFormat"></p>

    <img id="wreckImage" class="imgFormat" src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1dUQ3PQvtqBm-RvVFPk-yTOGtkkLwhTkp'> 
  

<script>
//table of all wrecks including link details and thumbnail picture sources

var wreckList = [


["Aberdeenshire",21,10,1910,"1dUQ3PQvtqBm-RvVFPk-yTOGtkkLwhTkp","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/aberdeenshire","This Aberdeen registered fishing trawler ran aground in heavy weather one mile south of Boddam, all 9 crew were rescued by breeches buoy.  She now lies, badly broken up, in about 14m of water."],
["Adventure",6,1,1922,"1kjZ7_i1DgTpn0Cane-PPCvh3Zclg-iWG","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/adventure","This Peterhead registered trawler struck a leftover WW1 mine which exploded midships and sank the vessel.  All her crew got off safely into another trawler.  She now lies at a depth of 71m."],
["Anvers",13,11,1940,"1X01MLV3UOR3MeeG53Ef4dRSQjuS26J_Z","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/anvers","A Belgian registered cargo ship carying scrap steel and bound for Methil, Fife.  She was bombed by German aircraft with the loss of 20 of her crew.  She now lies in 52m of water."],
["Astronomer",2,6,1940,"1244389oL_idnAUnK1euA2LuuAMnwhFyP","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/astronomer","A Liverpool registered cargo ship, she was carying boom equipment for use at the naval base in Scapa Flow, Orkney.  She was sunk by torpedoes from the U 58 with the loss of 5 of her crew, she now lies in 67m."],
["Atland",25,3,1943,"1DVNrzH_-76wbK8lQzNsUkFjBbcvmkMDT","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/atland","A Swedish registered cargo vessel of a unique \"Turret\" design.  She was carying iron ore, bound for Methil in Fife, when she collided with another ship in her convoy and sank with the loss of 19 of her crew.  She now lies in 64m."],
["Bel Lily",14,5,1917,"1mpfy0h8EWRyPA4hOoIufhkpYJK8i66Nk","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/bel-lily","A Grimsby registered trawler which hit a mine laid by UC 49 while fishing off Peterhead.  All 10 of her crew were lost in the sinking.  She now lies in 50m."],
["Bretagne",17,4,1917,"1tASywryz3ftU_bwUvgIQtzhBT6iDzTif","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/bretagne","Registered in Copenhagen, she was carying a cargo of coal from North Sheilds to Copenhagen when she was attacked by the U 45 and sunk by gunfire and torpedo.  All of the crew were rescued. She now lies in 61m."],
["Cairnavon",1,11,1925,"1xy0Q0gIVMk7H9VeedWe-onxFbLlRnu2N","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/cairnavon","She ran aground in dense fog while en route from Leith to Montreal with a general cargo, including coal, coke, rags and manganese.  All passengers and crew were rescued.  She now lies in 18m."],
["Cairnmona",30,10,1939,"1GQ5-RZnCyZksK0A6ImTr9FOqOrBgqrRF","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/cairnmona","Registered in Newcastle-upon-Tyne and a member of the Cairn line, she held a cargo of wool, gain, copper and zinc bound from Montreal to Leith when she was sunk by a torpedo from the U-13.  Three of the crew were lost.  She now lies in 51m."],
["Cape York",27,8,1940,"187e-rJxKrSfv7AhhB7u6d2QNjt9v4m2e","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/cape-york","Registered in Glasgow, she was loaded with grain, wood and lead ingots and bount for Methil, Fife, she was bombed JU88 bombers from Aalsburg.  She no lies in 93m."],
["Charles Goodanew",17,4,1917,"1pHvVDvD4avHgp5koBXU1-IgJ7MaWGRVg","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/charles-goodanew","Registered in Plymouth as an admiralty stores carrier, she was en route to the military base in Scapa Flow with a cargo of government stores when she was sunk by a mine laid by UC 45.  Only two of her crew of 15 survived.  She now lies in 52m."],
["Chicago",10,10,1894,"1E3uifEFlLHPQmDkCHUiyfBSCfGSmvJXC","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/chicago","A Sunderland registered cargo vessel, she was heading for Baltimore with a cargo of cement, pickled herrings and wine hen she ran aground on the rocks below New Slains Castle.  All of her crew were saved.  She now lies in 13m."],
["City of Osaka",23,9,1930,"192JpeG36zfcrmDZi07J6L7ezXC-BRaDx","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/city-of-osaka","A Liverpool registered cargo ship, she was carying a load of timber and bound for New York when she ran aground in thick fog.  All her rew were saved.  She now lies, broken up, in 12m.."],
["Constant Star",27,8,1987,"1VOYdSJwNFFQHTenLSrWm0HkB5hzAww-V","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/constant-star","A Peterhead registered fishing vessel, she was heading home to avoid bad weather when she ran aground on Skerry Rock just outside Peterhead harbour.  All her crew were saved by the lifeboat.  She now lies, broken up, in 15m."],
["Crisabelle Stephen",16,1,1939,"1_tjk5BSoDYRis1H7UVhssmQrKYmBQWiX","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/crisabelle-stephen","An Aberdeen registered trawler, she was rescued after running aground near Cruden Scaurs however she capsized while on tow back to Aberdeen with the loss of all 9 of her crew."],
["Dungonnell",24,2,1903,"1OQR8nYLPrkjjTlMxSfXgJrSkSmbaPR0y","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/dungonnell","A Glasgow registered cargo vessel, she was carying a load of telegraph poles from Shields, bound for Belfast in February, 1903.  She and her crew were never seen again."],
["Einar",16,8,1893,"1mlLbauYSN2v0LMxoAvegv3wXN0vtvOO4","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/einar","A Norwegian cargo vessel, she ran aground in fog while en route from Middlesbrough to Iceland with a cargo of salt.  She now lies in 8m."],
["Ethel Gwendoline",21,3,1890,"1ZKK759fiyP72VX6_nMn-vEVNGBqGuaEM","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/ethel-gwendoline","Registered in Cardiff, she had loaded coal and general cargo at Sunderland and was making for Inverness when she foundered off Cairnbulg during a south-easterly gale.  Six of her nine crew were lost.  She now lies in 56m. "],
["Flotta",6,11,1941,"1ZMRBJMxtGKxtgF072WZn_woemI694S50","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/flotta","A Royal Navy Isles Class minesweeper, she ran aground and was refloated a week later, however she soon foundered with the loss of 5 of her fourteen crew.  She now lies in 62m."],
["Fort Royal",9,2,1940,"16FjqsyVf6KNwNz-bRhVhPri1J7605YYj","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/fort-royal","Originally built as a trawler, she was requisitioned by the Royal Navy in 1939 and converted into an Aberdeen based minesweeper to patrol the north east of Scotland.  She was lost in an enemy aircraft raid and now lies in 63m."],
["Fram",1,2,1940,"1hetFvjjloV-RvXIdfE1x5-vpyhvW4cgq","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/fram","A Swedish registered cargo ship in ballast and sheltering from weather in Aberdour Bay, she was torpedoed by the U-13 and sank in two halves, with the loss of 10 of her 25 crew.  The bow lies in 37m, the stern in 46m."],
["Friedrich Bolte",16,2,1941,"1gY_SL_ejMXDvbFVs3qVOcMARuFakMBwc","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/friedrich-bolte","A German registered trawler which foundered six miles east of the Cruden Scares, the fate of her crew is unknown.  She now lies in 66m."],
["Gelsina",25,6,1917,"1wJVCSrOjPxZYxHp3H-CnYi6AvRfxicie","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/gelsina","A Grimsby registered trawler, requisitioned as a minesweeper but hit a mine laid by the UC 40. Five of her crew were lost.  She now lies in 62m."],
["Hit or Miss",3,12,1900,"1z_GMHCsGXmn21FRh1ynqj81Vn-iZG64t","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/hit-or-miss","A small Aberdeen registered trawler making its way to home when her boiler failed, drifting her onto Skerry Rock where she was holed and later foundered.  She now lies in 44m and close to two other small wrecks."],
["Kathleen",26,1,1914,"1tAD9BgzqY667MfX55scOwjAcrM5FCHFa","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/kathleen","Built in Belfast but registered in Aberdeen, she was lost with all hands in a gale whilst en route from Burghead to Middlesborough with a cargo of wood.  She now lies in 72m."],
["Kildale",3,11,1940,"1ntXKf7JLKHnDYoPkRFBUGI6Wzoyc3AWX","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/kildale","Registered in Whitby, she had loaded with sugar in the Dominican Republic and sailed accross the Atlantic in convoy.  She was en route to Methil, Fife when she was sunk by bombfire from German aircraft.  Two of her 37 crew were lost.  She now lies in 63m."],
["Lord Nelson",22,11,1940,"1HrhxFbQla2lHXjAQLifK7CwWiRGWr09D","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/lord-nelson","An Icelandic trawler, she was off Peterhead when she collided with another trawler, the Northman.  She soon foundered and sank.  All of her crew were taken aboard the Northman.  She now lies in 57m."],
["Maria W",22,2,1966,"120vueYAO8pIDAq0CVUW4_XIAB6CRStax","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/maria-w","A Dutch registered cargo vessel.  She was en route from Ghent to Scrabster carrying fertiliser when she became lost in thick fog.  She was blown stern first into Sandy Haven having struck the Skares and lost her propeller,  she became a total loss and now lies broken up and dispersed in 6m."],
["Mercator",1,12,1940,"1AVmn3dXcwOAhLvyCN7bZmSQs4ifswXDy","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/mercator","A Finnish registered cargo ship, she sailed from Buenos Aires to Leith with a cargo of coffee, maize, linseed, casein and groundnut meal.  From Leith she departed for Helsinki and was torpedoed off Peterhead by the U-21.  All but one of her crew were saved.  She now lies in 82m."],
["Muriel",17,12,1918,"14cF1CqsG-O4qOKGx2tWclLE_CAEk2Mtw","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/muriel","Registered in Newport, UK she was en route from the Tyne to Scapa Flow with a cargo of coal. Whilst passing Peterhead at 11:20 am she was struck by a torpedo fired by UC 58.  All of her crew were rescued.  She now lies in 48m."],
["Ormonde",16,2,1941,"1GL50qETlxY5EOk1Gy2gq4_Lt5sCwSYz_","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/ormonde","A Grimsby registered trawler, she was requisitioned by the Admiralty as an armed mine-sweeper.  She was patrolling off Cruden Bay when she was attacked and sunk by German aircraft.  All of her crew perished.  She now lies in 60m."],
["Prestonian",25,5,1915,"1hNVx9dnlS-86CaEWevOMAAvVka3avO0u","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/prestonian","Registered in Preston, she was on a voyage from Archangel to Dundee with a cargo of flax and timber when she ran aground at Aberdour Bay.  She now lies in 15m."],
["Remuera",16,8,1940,"13HfvbDsw3iSwr1TUFpTET2QrZEYO0RlB","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/remuera","One of our favourites, she was registered in Plymouth but built for the New Zealand Shipping Co. Ltd.  A large cargo liner, she was en route from Wellington and almost at her destination when she was attacked by aircraft and sunk by aerial torpedo.  All of the crew were rescued.  She now lies in 57m."],
["Robert Bowen",9,2,1940,"1IGH6Wpf5eXWkZ_L1QzAsbVPXIyElGL6t","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/robert-bowen","An armed trawler working out of Aberdeen on minesweeping duties patrolling the North East coast.  She was operating just north of Aberdeen when she was discovered by enemy aircraft and sunk by a direct bomb hit, killing all onboard."],
["Simonburn",20,10,1940,"1XJaajaPodSdLI19q3nqUHzeWFBvI1hQP","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/simonburn","A Newcastle registered cargo ship, she loaded with cargo in Montreal and was heading down the Buchan coast to Methil when she ran aground in a gale.  She was refloated but later foundered.  All of her crew were taken off by the Peterhead lifeboat.  She now lies on 54m."],
["Sofie Bakke",4,8,1940,"1ZSEP9PGfEEidW1IH2S4pMCLgKCO5Oc3v","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/sofie-bakke","A Swedish registered ship, she was bound for London with a general cargo loaded in South America when she collided with another ship in her convoy and sank.  All of her crew were rescued.  She now lies in 68m."],
["St Clement",5,4,1941,"1jK7XkvDJi77S8qebJKk0gEzT4Czr7Ygy","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/st-clement","An Aberdeen registered passenger and cargo carrier operating the Aberdeen to Caithness route, she was bombed and sunk by German aircraft with the loss of one of her crew.  She now lies in 55m."],
["St Fergus",31,12,1940,"1V32c-Zx0xzmOonbyAqPM9Y73PApZ3VVA","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/st-fergus","An Aberdeen registered passenger and cargo carrier operating the Aberdeen to Stromness route, she collided with a much larger ship, the SS Lima, and sank with the loss of at least one of her crew.  She now lies in 77m."],
["St Glen",6,9,1940,"1ZhjI6NtJbMPT3A8llvOr20RxkYSUEgbR","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/st-glen","A Newport registered cargo ship, she was en route from Freetown to Methil with a cargo of wheat and tinned corned beef when she was attacked and sunk by German aircraft.  Three of her crew were lost.  She now lies in 67m."],
["St Magnus",12,2,1918,"1po60xIz_c20-FkbGMZIVMHM8H4momBGV","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/st-magnus","The Aberdeen registered passenger and cargo carrier had sailed from Lerwick for Aberdeen and was just passing Peterhead when she was torpedoed by UC 58. Four of her passengers and one of her crew were lost.  She now lies in 49m."],
["Subworker",26,3,1913,"1j7M7kf2obN1oSReK2y1g7YBkW9VGiBvj","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/subworker","The London registered bucket dredger barge was under tow from the Clyde to Aberdeen when the tow parted and she foundered in heavy seas 16 miles off Rattray Head.  She now lies in 83m."],
["Taylor",30,9,1937,"1TS_Z5L1I7pkiU89C62TcE3OehCCNdw7P","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/taylor","The Sunderland registered steam lighter was on a voyage from Buckie to Sunderland with a cargo of sleepers, when she capsized and foundered off Peterhead. Her captain survived and was picked up by the Grimsby steam trawler Ocean Princess, however the remaining five crew were lost.  She now lies in 58m."],
["Trevorian",29,11,1943,"12i5WdIoo-j2Z9U5TvLlIUvs4J5dads91","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/trevorian","The St Ives registered cargo ship was on a voyage from Hull to the Mediterranean when she collided with and Icelandic trawler and sank.  The fate of her crew is unknown.  She now lies in 76m."],
["Trsat",7,9,1941,"1hS25UdOvh8jBGrwKL-kKZPpNOYKP38Zu","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/trsat","Registered in Cardiff, she was a steam coaster on passage from Reykjavik to Hull with a cargo of 845 tons of fish when she was bombed by a single Luftwaffe aircraft off Kinnaird Head.   Three men were lost in the sinking.  She now lies in 68m."],
["Tynemouth Castle",9,12,1939,"1MvcCuyzoPJFTY7A_4PMp9wQ-718x5lqV","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/tynemouth-castle","A Grimsby registered trawler, she struck the Cruden Scares and founderd 3 miles south east of Cruden Bay.  The fate of her crew is unknown, she now lies in 58m."],
["U-1206",14,4,1945,"1kXvJJV01z9NVM2KCiHpXpyvVzBscEh6J","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/u-1206","A type VII-C U-boat, she was on patrol off the Buchan coast when she was abandoned and scuttled.  All of the crew escaped in the liferafts and either made it ashore or were picked up by local boats.  Three of the crew lost their life attepting to scale the cliffs south of Boddam."],
["U 77",7,7,1916,"1a9zzZKQjjuULnLa4waT8Ka7_qCvispv0","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/u-77","A type UE 1 mine laying U-boat from WW1.  Lost, presumed in an accident, while on a mine laying mission off Kinnaird Head, Fraserburgh.  All of the crew were lost."],
["Windward Ho",9,5,1917,"1J3AwYcyTn1YoK57Espdt2ovjr5aeSbKx","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/windward-ho","A Hull registered trawler en route from Hull to the fishing grounds she detonated a German contact mine which had been laid by UC 49.  All eight crew were lost when she sank three miles SSE of Buchan Ness.  She now lies in 50m."],
["Wrangler",6,10,1941,"13PfwElHM-e3BSvz-8U9H_wlT9bpJavz-","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/wrangler","A Southampton registered hopper-barge she was engaged in close-inshore salvage work to the north of Peterhead when she ran aground on the Girdle Wears and foundered.  She now lies 48m."],
["Zitella",7,2,1940,"17-JD6a6okDe7OlZulVPHLp2VgfoxZtvf","https://www.buchandivers.com/wrecks/zitella","A London registered steam ship, she was outward bound from Narvik in Norway to Middlesborough with a cargo of iron ore in her hold and with 33 crew members on board when she ran aground in poor weather and fog at Longhaven, just south of Buchan Ness.  All of her crew were rescued and she now lies broken up in 10m."],
    ]

//use todays date to find which wreck to display
let wreckDetails = findWreck();
let wreckIndex = wreckDetails[0]; //pointer to the wreck in table to display
let ageText = wreckDetails[1]; //number of years since sank
let title = wreckDetails[2]; //formatted title page either wreck of day or anniversary
let srcPath = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + wreckList[wreckIndex][4]  //

var paraText = "The " + "<a href=\"" + wreckList[wreckIndex][5] +"\">" + wreckList[wreckIndex][0] + "</a>" + " sank " + ageText + wreckList[wreckIndex][6];

document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
document.getElementById("wreckText").innerHTML = paraText;
document.getElementById("wreckImage").src = srcPath

function findWreck() {// returns index of wreck to display plus sinking anniversary text and title in 3 element array

    var today = new Date();
    var dayCount = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];  //cumulative days in year at start of month
    var mn = today.getMonth();
    var dn = today.getDate();
  var yn = today.getYear() + 1900; //getYear returns year since 1900 so add 1900
    var dayOfYear = dayCount[mn] + dn;
    
    //loop through table until wreck found with with day/month same as today
    
    var index = 999;
    
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < wreckList.length; i++) {
        if (wreckList[i][1] == dn && wreckList[i][2] == mn + 1) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    
    if (index < 999) { //wreck sank this day was found
        return [index, yn - wreckList[index][3] + " years ago today. ", "Wrecked on this day: " + wreckList[index][0]];
    } else { //no wreck anniversary so choose any wreck based on day number mod num. wrecks
        index = (dayOfYear) % wreckList.length;
      var dateSinceSinking = yn - wreckList[index][3];
        return [index, dateSinceSinking + " years ago. ", "Wreck of the day: " + wreckList[index][0]];
    }
    
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Drive as an image host with their (undocumented, I believe) `/uc` endpoint [seems to have been broken in January 2024](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488?pli=1). I’m on mobile right now so cannot confirm, but your developer console is highly likely reporting `403 Forbidden` for these images. There are many hacky workarounds described in the bug tracker link above.

However, what they all fail to mention is that **Google Drive is not intended to be used as an HTTP CDN for static assets.** This is directly evidenced by the fact that the report linked above has been closed as
`Won’t fix (intended behavior)`. Furthermore, [Google deprecated and removed a legacy feature for using Google Drive as a host for static websites and assets around August 2015](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?m=1), furthering the idea that this isn’t the way this product was intended to be used outside of said feature. From the article:

> For those who use this feature to serve non-user content to web and mobile applications, [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) offers a solution for this purpose.

My recommendation would be to find and use a proper host for your static assets, instead of co-opting a cloud file storage provider that is not intended to be (ab)used as a quasi-CDN for your content.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem.  I have loaded all my images into a Google cloud storage bucket, changed the URL references and it works fine.  Code is much neater and the static data is simpler to maintain - and added benefit.  I would never have figured this out myself - documentation is pretty poor.  thanks for your help.