# Anonymous access to Google Drive from JavaScript in browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of public images in a Google Drive that I'd like to display on a website. There is no server-side programming access on the website; I have to do all programming in JavaScript on the browser. What I'd like to do is get a listing of the files in the public folder and then I can make the appropriate HTML.

But I cannot figure out a reasonable way to get the list of files. I have found lots of discussion about how to do this with server-side APIs -- Drive app, Google's REST API -- but none seem suitable for browser JavaScript, just node.js. The REST API in particular seems either to require OAuth 2.0 or an API key. Clearly the OAuth credentials cannot live in a browser-based JavaScript, and I'm a little leery about putting the API key there, even if the API key is highly restricted. I've also found a few old Stack Overflow answers with pointers to APIs that promise anonymous access, but those all seem to point to dead links; the APIs have apparently been withdrawn.

Of course I can just access the page via a regular URL, but the HTML data that comes back is a pretty complicated script, and parsing the information out of that would be difficult (not to mention pretty fragile when the display changes).

Am I missing some API? Or am I overthinking the security aspects about putting the API key into a public script?

Comment: Google drive is not a file hosting service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat soft duplicate of a question I answered just yesterday ([Script has started showing broken image icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937978/script-has-started-showing-broken-image-icon/77938017#77938017)); the core of the message is that Google Drive is not designed nor intended to be used to host static assets for anonymous consumption. As of last month (January 2024), many of the workarounds used to replace the legacy Google Drive Website Hosting features deprecated in 2015 have become unreliable or outright broken. Your analysis that client-side JavaScript facilities being weak/nonexistent is also an indicator of this fact.

In short, what you're looking to do simply isn't practically possible by design, and is somewhat akin to trying to drive a nail with a banana. After a significant effort you *might* be able to achieve the result you're looking for, but using the right tool for the job (i.e., a proper image host, CDN or similar) will net you much better results and a more maintainable solution in the long run.

You *might* be able to hack something together using a bundler like `webpack` where it Base64 encodes the images in the HTML document itself, but this would significantly inflate the size of your HTML document and may not be desirable for you dependent on your use case.

If you're hosting this HTML somewhere, I'm not sure what would preclude you from hosting the image assets alongside the HTML document and making relative references to them in your HTML markup.